# Using negation of formal limit definition

Tags: calculus

Using the following definition:

> $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} f(x) \ne L \iff $ there exists $\varepsilon  > 0$ such that for all $\delta  > 0$ such that for some $x \ne a$ we have $\left| {x - a} \right| < \delta $ yet $ \left| {f(x) - L} \right| \ge \varepsilon $

Prove that:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 2}\; (x + 3) \ne 4$$
but, I don't want $\varepsilon$ to equal some fixed value, I want to find the greatest value for $\varepsilon$ that proves this.

Also, is there any textbooks or any online resource discussing this negation with a lot of details and examples?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, what is the difference?

Comment: Your definition, @AhmedAli , is lacking "there exists $\;x\neq a\;$..."

Comment: This is the negation of the definition, I am saying that $x$ doesn't equal $a$ so that I could omit $0<$ part.

Comment: Doesn't for all become for some?

Comment: About the "and" part, thanks I checked the definition again and you are right thanks

Comment: The notation used in calculus books for definition usually is not standard. This is the definition of a limit: $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L \quad\leftrightarrow\quad  (\forall  \epsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(\forall x\in \Bbb R)(0<|x-a|<\delta\to |f(x)-L|<\epsilon)$$
Now try to negate it correctly.

Comment: @AhmedAli, you *must* negate the last $\;\forall\;$ in the definition, the correct one, given above by Minimus.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this without making $\varepsilon$ equal a certain value?

Comment: You have to prove that an $\epsilon$ exists. Most easy way to prove that is to determine a certain value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $\;\epsilon =1\;$ , and now we have that

$$|x+3-4|=|x-1|\ge 1\iff\begin{cases}x-1\ge 1\iff x\ge 2&,\;or\\{}\\x-1\le-1\iff x\le 0\end{cases}$$

Thus, for **any** $\;\delta >0\;$ ,  even if it is very small, take $\;x\ge 2\;$ s.t. $\;x-2<\delta\;$ , and then, as seen above, $\;|(x+3)-4|\ge 1\;\ldots$